# How do i parse and extract untidy Excel data?

Tags: r, excel

I need to create a function that parses and splits untidy excel data and ultimately saves them as csv files.

More specifically, for each Excel File, for each Sheet, i need to have 2 data frames(one that contains a table, and one that contains all the headers). For each Sheet, the layout is the same(same headers, same table)

I must NOT use rows to divide the headers, rather character names.

How can I split it?

[image]

- The headers are: title, pages, copies, year, end. The first four are 3 
  rows above the table, end is 2 rows below it.
- The table has 5 columns: id, glucose, insulin, crp, ffa.
- The table has 4 rows(5 if you include column names above)
- The headers should be like so in the final df: 
     title:one, pages:many, copies:200, year:2019, end:afternoon.
- Currently, the headers and the corresponding values do not exist in the 
  same cell, but in adjacent cells.

I will do my best to provide further clarification, if asked.

I already have a code to write them as csv after the parsing, so that's done.

I already have a function that splits Excel Sheets.

Now i only need to split into 2 data frames.

I tried using `tidyxl`, but for some reason it doesn't open the file. It states that there is an `error("zip file cannot be opened")`, however the file is not a zip, it is an xlsx i just created.

I tried filtering by character, but it didn't work(or i couldn't make it work).

```
#file.choose()
my_path <- "C:\\Users\\Βύρωνας\\Desktop\\BYRON\\Miscellaneous\\test.xlsx"
cel <- xlsx_cells(path = my_path, sheets = Sheet1) #doesn't work
cells <- readxl::read_excel(my_path, col_names = F)

cells <- as_cells(cells)
rectify(cells, character, numeric)
str(cells)

#idea: which row and which columns have the top_left and bottom_right?
corners <- 
filter(cells, !is.na(character),
     !(character %in% c("title", "pages", "copies", "year", "end")))

partition(cells, corners)

#if it doesn't work, use subset? or find the row that contains the end and 
#get the inbetween space?
```

If it helps, here is the code (it works) for importing and splitting sheets:

```
library(readxl)
read_excel_allsheets <-function(filename, tibble = FALSE) {
sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
 if(!tibble) 
  x <-lapply(x, as.data.frame)
  names(x) <- sheets
x
}
```

In the mean time, i have reached this far:

```
sheet <- 1
read1 <- readxl::read_excel(my_path, sheet = sheet)

skip_rows <- NULL
col_skip <- 0
search_string1 <- "id"
search_string2 <- "end"
max_cols_to_search <- 6
max_rows_to_search <- 20

while (length(skip_rows) == 0) {
  col_skip <- col_skip + 1
  if (col_skip == max_cols_to_search) break
  skip_rows <- 
which(stringr::str_detect(read1[1:max_rows_to_search,col_skip][[1]],
                                     search_string1)) - 0

}


read2 <- readxl::read_excel(
  my_path,
  sheet = sheet,
  skip = skip_rows
)
```

This help me get rid of the top headers, which is good, but i still can't get rid of the bottom one.

Comment: You can post images on imgur.com and link to them

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i just edited it :)